# Call SQL function with parameters and WHERE clause FROM C# ExecuteReaderAsync

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

faced with such a problem here: have a method what returns result of SQL function selection, everything works fine when call function without WHERE clause, but when call it with @search I got nothing in result, but same query works perfect in MsSQL Manager.

*(Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, MsSqlServer Express 2016)*

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<SelectedJob>> GetFunction(int? moduleId, int? specialGroupId, string search)
    {
        var commandText = "SELECT * FROM GUI.fGetSelectedJobs(@ModuleID, @SpecialGroupID)";
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@ModuleID", moduleId }, { "@SpecialGroupID", specialGroupId } };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            commandText = "SELECT * FROM GUI.fGetSelectedJobs(@ModuleID, @SpecialGroupID) WHERE JobName LIKE '%@search%'";
            parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@ModuleID", moduleId }, { "@SpecialGroupID", specialGroupId }, { "@search", search } };
        }

        var rows = await Database.QueryAsync(commandText, parameters);

        return rows?.Select(ParseRow).ToList();
    }
```

Part of QueryAsync method:

```
var command = CreateCommand(commandText, parameters);
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                   //Some job
                }
```

But it always empty when command builded with WHERE clause:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: what is GUI in GUI.fGetSelectedJobs.

Comment: Try using SELECT * FROM dbo.fGetSelectedJobs if GUI is not the schema name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` part should be `WHERE JobName LIKE @search"`, and add the `%` in your search string:

```
parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@ModuleID", moduleId },
         { "@SpecialGroupID", specialGroupId }, { "@search", "%" + search + "%"  } };
```

Comment: Or just in query `JobName LIKE '%" + @search + "%'`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand,but I don't agree @Fabio, that wouldn't use a parameter for the query, would just be a string concatenation.Maybe you meant something like `LIKE '%' + @search+ '%'`

Comment: My typo, sorry - `"SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE JobName LIKE '%' + @search +'%'"` will be another approach.